# POST response 0 before actual message

Tags: c, json, http, sockets, post

So I did some post request in C, simply with write and read.
The server is not made by me, so I was wondering if we send POST request to http from write and read function, is it normal to have the POST response as "0\r\n" or sometimes even just nothing (Content-length=0), and when I re-read the response, I can read the actual message?

Is this because how POST request work?

the flow is sth like this

```
REQUEST ===========>
                     <============ 0\r\n
                     <============ response
                     <============ 0\r\n
```

my POST request header would look like

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
authorization: bearer
Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 242

{"some":"json"}
```

and sometimes the response is just blank before the actual response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 91
ETag: W/"5b-Jn5H7ksEN9TK+a5eBmSVDbbNQMU"
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2022 09:09:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"some":"json2"}
```

I'm not sure if im tagging this question right, im new to rest api, but any help would be appreciated, tqu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *strange* (because of the 0) but not at all uncommon, per se. It looks like an example of [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). The terminating "0" is the correct termination for chunked transfer.

I guess the initial "0" *might* be a keep-alive of sorts, or a clever attempt of confirming that the server is indeed processing the request, and/or artificially lowering the dreaded [TTFB](https://web.dev/ttfb/) metric when it's measured against the actual *content* rather than the first byte of headers. It doesn't sound right to me, because I feel that it ought to signal the *end* of the connection.

Check out the headers of the POST response to verify that you're indeed receiving `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, and double-check that the initial sequence is *indeed* "0".

Comment: does this means we actually have to loop read() for chunked transfer encoding? I'm sorry if my question is weird, i have zero idea on this

Comment: Yes, CTE is handled by reading a CRLF terminated hex length string, then reading that number of bytes, and so on until you get a length of zero. Then you may close the connection (if Connection: close, then you're *expected* to close the connection), or are allowed to send a further request.

Comment: So other than CTE, there isn't supposed to be any other situation (considering things went normal) that would cause 0/r/n to arrive first before the actual msg right?

Comment: esp for http json request?

Comment: @dibii none. And CTE must be specified in the response headers - you **can't** be expected to somehow autodetect it (imagine a CSV file of one column where the first value of the first row is numeric. That would be a legitimate text/plain file and that data is *content*, not a *length specifier*).